# Elm : Combining both actions.signal and keyboard input in foldp

Tags: elm, keyboard-input

Currently I'm experimenting with elm (so consider me a beginner) and was wondering about the following,

I have defined the following model :

```
model = foldp update initialModel actions.signal
```

I understand how `foldp` works, it calls my update method to change the `initialModel` whenever an action is performed (called from my html buttons etc).

However, now I'm struggling to find out how I can integrate keypresses into this model since `foldp` only accepts a single changing signal.

So I would like to get something like this

```
model = foldp update initialModel (actions.signal + Keyboard.arrows)
```

I tried to play around with the `merge` method but I just can't seem to be able to get it working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you have an `actions` mailbox, do you have an `Action` type defined too? Then you can expand it to include a `Keypress` action:

```
type Action =
  ...
  | KeyPress { x : Int, y : Int }

inputs =
  Signal.merge actions.signal (Signal.map KeyPress Keyboard.arrows)

model =
  Signal.foldp update initialModel inputs
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Signal.merge - take a look at http://elm-lang.org/guide/reactivity#signals for an overview of the signal map